# mt_rand same number, symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, numbers, fosuserbundle

i'm currently working with symfony2. I've created my user entity as i want it to be, but i have a massive problem and don't know what it's caused by:

i want to have a random number with the length of 10 characters for the ID.

ID field:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * 
     */
    protected $id;
```

setId, so a random number get's generated, before persisting

```
/**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return UserReg
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $number = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
        $this->id = $number;

        return $this;
    }
```

If i run the same function on a completely fresh controller that does nothing but generate the number and give it out .... it works. Everytime i refresh the page a random number appears.

But somehow it doesn't work with the user registration. The same number gets generated over and over again. Before i used the Lifecycle Callbacks and tried to generate the number within the register controller, same result ... i'm now trying to generate the number directly withing the entity as you can see and still.... the same number, over and over again.

What am i missing?

I hope somebody can help ...

Regards

Edit:

SOMETIMES a different random number gets generated, but most of the times it's the same. F.e:
1. register: 2147483647
2. register: 1749450073
3. register: duplicate entry ( 2147483647 ).

I just took a good look at the error message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO UserReg (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, id, firstname, lastname, birthdate, secretq, secreta, registered, banned, frozen, creditpoints, country, verified, referralcode, referree, messages) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["testmail3@test.com", "testmail3@test.com", "testmail3@test.com", "testmail3@test.com", 0, "gqd6kqolwk084gwg4ggwwsc8kokwk0k", "$2y$13$gqd6kqolwk084gwg4ggwwetuZOQlZzCjlPt7HmZ4RMp7LBITBZ8Wy", null, 0, 0, null, "i_cVQFp-cG5KyQ70eqMZH6y32lAZEtEsvWkIG7bbcrQ", null, "a:0:{}", 0, null, **2179120243**, "Max", "Mustermann", "1894-01-01 00:00:00", "What was your childhood nickname", "asd", "2014-02-01 18:30:03", "no", null, "150", "Austria", "no", "c46c6fcaaaae7a606fd25185ec860fd1", null, "0"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '**2147483647**' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't get what's wrong: the sql insert shows a different ID than the one in the error message.

Comment: The database column you're inserting into doesn't support numbers that large. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html for precise supported number ranges.

Comment: Do you seed MT somehow?

Comment: @Ninja Andrej you also repeat the FOSUserBundle functionality (`banned`, `frozen` properties). And yes, ID should be used as a database AI field.

Comment: @AndrzejOśmiałowski Do you mean the "locked" from the userbundle?

Comment: @NinjaAndrej Yes, exactly + users roles. DRY rule really rocks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're reaching the max size for an integer, 2^31-1 = 2147483647. Generate the numbers as a string and you'll be fine.

That said, you should just use MySQL's sequential `auto_incremenet` for IDs instead.

Comment: thank you. Dunno how i could have missed it. Well, i've changed some stuff now anyways, having a "real" AI ID and a unique user ID ... which is now finally working.